# how to remove trailing (*) in robotframework

Tags: string, robotframework

How to remove the asterisk after initials? `first*initials *******`

tried to remove asterisk by `${text}=     Evaluate    '${text}'.replace('*',"")    mode=right` however it removes all asterisk. I just want to remove the asterisk after initials.

Comment: Can you try with this `${text}'.replace('**',"")`?

Comment: What about `${text}=     Evaluate    '${text}'.rstrip('*')`?